# Engine knock due to contaminated cylinder, is there a way to purge? 1998 Ford F-150 4.6L

Tags: engine, ford, knock

I am an apprentice for a small shop and we recently replaced a 4.6L engine on a 1998 F-150 due to knocking problems (important). The engine we swapped it for was presumably in good running condition, and immediately after we swapped it once we turned it on we heard a loud klinking noise as if the cylinder had a piece of metal (possibly a screw) in it. After leaving the engine running for some time and pressing the gas the noise lowered as if the screw had settled, and now all you hear when the truck is running is a persistant knock like if the screw is hitting against something. Now, since the original engine had to be replaced due to knocking, I am uncertain whether there is really a piece of metal in the cylinder or if there is anything that could have affected the new engine in the same way as the old one.

So two questions, if there is no screw inside the engine, what could have caused the loud knocking in the beginning and then have a settled, steady knocking? Or two, if there is a screw inside the engine, is it possible to recover the screw and fix the knock? A type of purge, on the cylinders or exhaust?

I should also mention that the engine runs very well, I have personally test drove the truck and it didn't lose any power, and torque was consistent.

Comment: If you suspected there was some hard, foreign object in one of the cylinders, why did you continue to let the engine run?  I think it would be better to turn it off immediately, then look inside the cylinder with a boroscope.

In fact, even if it isn't a screw, etc.,  a boroscope would still be a good idea (in the case of excessive carbon build-up, etc.)